# How do I download a Google Sheet (Not workbook) in pipe delimited format from Google Drive using Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, google-drive-realtime-api, google-sheets-api

I'm coding to download a file from google drive to local system using google drive api. Below is my code. I've following questions:

1) Is there a way to specify sheet number to download only that from a workbook or complete workbook will be downloaded?

2) We have MIMETYPE 'text/csv', is there a way to save them using other delimiter say , pipe line?

3) Can we specify the location of download? Right now it's downloading where python script is.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file , client , tools
import io
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload


try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

#Set the scope for authorization and specify json file    
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret.json'

#Atleast once we will have to allow our program to access document, after that it would be stored in storage.json file
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
credz = store.get()
if not credz or credz.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET , SCOPES)
    credz = tools.run_flow(flow,store,flags)\
            if flags else tools.run(flow,store)
DRIVE = build('drive','v2',http=credz.authorize(Http()))

MIMETYPE='text/csv'
file_id='1p3yRgi093TKbsBrxkUkV1cP-6h8dWUIKXycU62i9Arc'
request = DRIVE.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,mimeType=MIMETYPE)

fh = io.FileIO('Google App Scripts for beginner.csv','wb')
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
```